# PDFTron - How to display multiple pre-defined regions in a page?

Tags: javascript, pdftron

I'm learning to use PDFTron in my Javascript application and I'd like to show only pre-defined regions in a page instead of showing a full page. If there are no pre-defined regions then a full page will be displayed.

I was trying to use ***cropPages*** but it only works once per page.

Here is an example. Once the document is loaded, only pre-defined regions will be shown as snippets for that page.
[pdftron snippets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlYMQ.png)

Later I can click on the snippet to have a full view of the page.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.